Is it possible to add Garomond font to Evolution?

I volunteer for an association and I have to send mails from this associations e-mail address. I would like to use Evolution client, but the association requires me to use the Garomond font in e-mails (so that they all look the same). Is it possible to add this font to Evolution? If yes, how?
Thanks in advance!
